# accessing rows in a sparse matriox in python

Tags: python, sparse-matrix

I have stored sparse matrix in a variable sparse_mat

```
sparse_mat = sparse.coo_matrix((freq,(data_obs,data_feature)))

sparse_mat
<540x5550 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.string_'>'
with 9068 stored elements in COOrdinate format>
```

Now I want to access the first row of this sparse matrix

I am trying

```
 sparse_mat[1:,]
```

But the error it gives is

```
TypeError: 'coo_matrix' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

How could this be done. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should be using [scipy.sparse](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html) for storing and manipulating sparse matrix instead of rolling out a home grown one.

Comment: I used the idea from there only:                      sparse_mat=sparse.coo_matrix((freq,(data_obs,data_feature)))

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sparse_mat.getrow(1)` (see http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.coo_matrix.html). It returns a sparse matrix, which you can convert to a dense one if necessary with `.todense()`

Comment: Its still not working for me.the data freq is an array with dtype s46.I guess that might be causing problem

Comment: Sorry, but what is dtype s46? I only know the basic ones. I tried to create an array with `dtype=numpy.dtype('s46')` and get an error.

Comment: >>> freq
array(['1', '1', '1', ..., '1', '1', '1'], 
      dtype='|S46')

Comment: Okay; if you try `sparse_mat.data[1,:]` perhaps? But I'm not sure it's very efficient.